# How to fetch large number of records from Snowflake from Mule 4 API

Tags: pagination, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mule4

I am new to Mulesoft and have a requirement to connect to Snowflake and fetch records do little bit of mapping and update them to another system.

The queries take person id, last modified date, date range and if nothing passed should get all records as shown the queries below

The results are returned for queries where modified date and date range are for short period, however for longer last modified date and date range getting error.
For the error-ed ones I get - `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host...`

It looks like their system has close to Million records.

`select * from Person where LAST_MODIFIED_DATE = 2020-12-15T00:00:00`  - works

`select * from Person where PERSON_ID =123456 and LAST_MODIFIED_DATE between 2012-12-15T00:00:00 and 2022-12-15T00:00:00` - error

`select * from Person where LAST_MODIFIED_DATE between 2011-12-15T00:00:00 and 2012-12-15T00:00:00` - works

`select * from Person` -  error

I also noticed that if I increase the query timeout from 30  seconds to 240 seconds it doesn't make any difference to the time it throw-ed the  error. It looks like Snowflake closes the connection after a certain time If records fetching crosses that time. I also changed the query timeout to 1 hour but got the same above error in seconds. Is there any changed needed at the snowflake end?

I can't see any error code returned, in the Mule logs could see below after the query execution
`org.mule.service.http.impl.service.server.grizzly.BaseResponseCompletionHandler: HTTP response sending task failed with error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

`Message               : Client connection was closed`

`Error type            : MULE:SOURCE_RESPONSE_SEND`

I am connecting to Snowflake using Snowflake connector (for select) as shown the screenshot below I have configured query timeout for 1 hour as well.

[image]

Also I observed that when I debug it, the processer passes from the Snowflake connector to the next process which is a dataweave component transforming the response to JSON. The debug shows it has response payload from snowflake as shown below (size =101). But this size is not right because for other queries which are working for short range dates its the same size and same same media type but the actual response has more than 101 records.

[image]

[image]

How do I implement this solution in Mule 4? Do I need to implement pagination if yes how?
The response has 8 fields.

please find logs below

```
Message               : Client connection was closed
Element               : *.xml:13
Element DSL           : <http:listener config-ref="*******-httpListenerConfig" path="/***/*">
<ee:repeatable-file-store-stream bufferUnit="MB"></ee:repeatable-file-store-stream>
<http:response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus default 200]">
<http:headers><![CDATA[
#[vars.outboundHeaders default {}]
]]></http:headers>
</http:response>
<http:error-response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus default 500]">
<http:body><![CDATA[
#[payload]
]]></http:body>
<http:headers><![CDATA[
#[vars.outboundHeaders default {}]
]]></http:headers>
</http:error-response>
</http:listener>
Error type            : MULE:SOURCE_RESPONSE_SEND
FlowStack             : 
Payload Type          : org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:470)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.writeSimpleBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:540)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.server.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:99)
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.server.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:36)
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.server.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:151)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error code? How are you connecting to snowflake?  Is it using snowflake connector or db connector?

Comment: Hi Harshank,  Thanks for your reply. I have updated the answers in the main question itself.  Let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Can you run the query directly in Snowflake using its UI and with the same role as being used by Mule? Snowflake has various timeout parameters that may be killing the query

Comment: Can you send more info from error log? You should see a "Element DSL" part in stack trace. The error that you shared seems to be an error related to http listener. More error info can help clarify that

Comment: Hi Harshank, updated the main question with logs from stack trace, in the logs could see 'Element DSL' referring to http listener only. Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: Hi NickW,  Thanks for your reply. Looks like the queries are all working ok from snowflake end, but I need to check with them on whether they executed the queries with same role as Mule one, will get back to you on that.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring at HTTP Listener, not at the Snowflake query. The error `Client connection was closed` generally occurs when the client closes its connection (eg- like in case of Timeout). It looks like you are making the HTTP Client wait for the response from your long running query which is not ideal for HTTP request. I would recommend you to run the query in async and not make the client wait for the response. You will have to update your API Specs accordingly.